# How to use multiple React Native DateTimePicker

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I am new learner in react-native. I have to create a form that have multiple datetimepicker. How can I achieve that. Currently my code is messy and I would like to simplify it. For now, I just create multiple variable for each datetimepicker. This make my code longer and repeatable. So I really hope someone could help me. Thank you.

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startbid: new Date(),
      startbidMode: 'date',
      startbidShow: false,
      endbid: new Date(),
      endbidMode: 'date',
      endbidShow: false,
      startservice: new Date(),
      startserviceMode: 'date',
      startserviceShow: false,
    };
  }

  setStartbidDate = (event, startbid) => {
    startbid = startbid || this.state.startbid;

    this.setState({
      startbidShow: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? true : false,
      startbid,
    });
  }

  setEndbidDate = (event, endbid) => {
    endbid = endbid || this.state.endbid;

    this.setState({
      endbidShow: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? true : false,
      endbid,
    });
  }

  setStartserviceDate = (event, startservice) => {
    startservice = startservice || this.state.startservice;

    this.setState({
      startserviceShow: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? true : false,
      startservice,
    });
  }

  show1 = startbidMode => {
    this.setState({
      startbidShow: true,
      startbidMode,
    });
  }

  show2 = endbidMode => {
    this.setState({
      endbidShow: true,
      endbidMode,
    });
  }

  show3 = startserviceMode => {
    this.setState({
      startserviceShow: true,
      startserviceMode,
    });
  }

  datepicker1 = () => {
    this.show1('date');
  }

  datepicker2 = () => {
    this.show2('date');
  }

  datepicker3 = () => {
    this.show3('date');
  }
```

And this is my code for the form.

```
<Form >
    <Label style={styles.labelForm}>Start Bid</Label>
    <Item rounded style={styles.inputs}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.datepicker1} style={{flexDirection:"row", alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Thumbnail source={require('../assets/images/icons/date.png')} style={styles.icons}/>
            <Text style={{paddingHorizontal:10}}>{startbid.getDate() + '-' + (startbid.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + startbid.getFullYear()}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        { startbidShow && 
        <DateTimePicker 
            value={startbid}
            mode={startbidMode}
            display="default"
            onChange={this.setStartbidDate} 
        />
        }
    </Item>

    <Label style={styles.labelForm}>End Bid</Label>
    <Item rounded style={styles.inputs}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.datepicker2} style={{flexDirection:"row", alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Thumbnail source={require('../assets/images/icons/date.png')} style={styles.icons}/>
            <Text style={{paddingHorizontal:10}}>{endbid.getDate() + '-' + (endbid.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + endbid.getFullYear()}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        { endbidShow && 
        <DateTimePicker 
            value={endbid}
            mode={endbidMode}
            display="default"
            onChange={this.setEndbidDate} 
        />
        }
    </Item>

    <Label style={styles.labelForm}>Start Service</Label>
    <Item rounded style={styles.inputs}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.datepicker3} style={{flexDirection:"row", alignItems:'center'}}>
            <Thumbnail source={require('../assets/images/icons/date.png')} style={styles.icons}/>
            <Text style={{paddingHorizontal:10}}>{startservice.getDate() + '-' + (startservice.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + startservice.getFullYear()}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        { startserviceShow && 
        <DateTimePicker 
            value={startservice}
            mode={startserviceMode}
            display="default"
            onChange={this.setStartserviceDate} 
        />
        }
    </Item>

    <View style={{paddingBottom:30}}>
        <Button block
            onPress={this.onClickSubmitButton}>
            <Text>Submit</Text>
        </Button>
    </View>

</Form>
```

Is there any way that I could making the code more clean and less code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it through my hook. I call the react component through a function

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, Picker } from 'react-native'
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker'

function useInput() {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('date');
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const showMode = (currentMode) => {
        setShow(true);
        setMode(currentMode);
    };
    const showDatepicker = () => {
        showMode('date');
    };

    const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
        const currentDate = selectedDate || date
        setShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
        setDate(currentDate);
    }
    return {
        date,
        showDatepicker,
        show,
        mode,
        onChange
    }
}

export const MainScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const input = useInput(new Date())
    const input2 = useInput(new Date())
return (
        <View >
           <Button              
              onPress={input.showDatepicker}
              title={input.date.toLocaleDateString()} />
              {input.show && (
                   <DateTimePicker
                   testID="dateTimePicker1"
                   value={input.date}
                   mode={input.mode}
                   is24Hour={true}
                   display="default"
                   onChange={input.onChange}
                   />
               )}

            <Button              
              onPress={input2.showDatepicker}
              title={input2.date.toLocaleDateString()} />
              {input2.show && (
                   <DateTimePicker
                   testID="dateTimePicker2"
                   value={input2.date}
                   mode={input2.mode}
                   is24Hour={true}
                   display="default"
                   onChange={input2.onChange}
                    />
              )}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### For multiple datetimepicker in class component

---

```
    import { differenceInDays, parseISO } from "date-fns";
    import DateTimePicker from "@react-native-community/datetimepicker";
    import { Overlay } from "react-native-elements";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { rentStartDate: new Date(),
      rentEndDate: new Date(),
      startDate: "",
      endDate: "",
      visible: false,
      visible2: false,}
   this.onChangeStart = this.onChangeStart.bind(this);
    this.onChangeEnd = this.onChangeEnd.bind(this);

}
 toggleOverlay() {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  }
  toggleOverlay2() {
    this.setState({ visible2: !this.state.visible2 });
  }

  onChangeStart(event, selectedDate) {
    let currentDate = selectedDate || this.state.rentStartDate;
    this.setState({
      visible: Platform.OS === "ios",
      rentStartDate: currentDate,
    });
    let mydate = JSON.stringify(currentDate)
      .split("T")[0]
      .trim()
      .replace('"', "");
    this.setState({ startDate: mydate });
  }
  onChangeEnd(event, Date) {
    let currentDate2 = Date || this.state.rentEndDate;
    let mydate1 = JSON.stringify(currentDate2)
      .split("T")[0]
      .trim()
      .replace('"', "");

    let day = differenceInDays(
      parseISO(mydate1),
      parseISO(this.state.startDate)
    );
    let calculate = Math.round(day * this.state.price.replace("$", ""));

    this.setState({
      endDate: mydate1,
      visible2: !this.state.visible2,
      PriceValue: calculate,
    });
  }
  render() {
return(    <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: "row",
              padding: 5,
              justifyContent: "space-evenly",
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ flex: 0.4 }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Start Date</Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  marginBottom: 5,
                  height: 40,
                  borderRadius: 2,
                  color: "black",
                  borderColor: "rgba(38, 38, 38,0.8)",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  backgroundColor: "white",
                  paddingEnd: 5,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 14,
                    paddingLeft: 5,
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                    color: "black",
                  }}
                >
                  {this.state.startDate}
                </Text>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.toggleOverlay()}>
                  <Image
                    source={require("../images/calendar_ic_gray.png")}
                    style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }}
                  />
                </TouchableHighlight>
                <Overlay
                  isVisible={this.state.visible}
                  onBackdropPress={() => {
                    this.toggleOverlay();
                  }}
                >
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 5 }}>
                    <Icon
                      name="ios-calendar"
                      size={26}
                      resizeMode={"contain"}
                      style={{
                        elevation: 5,
                        justifyContent: "flex-start",
                        alignSelf: "flex-start",
                        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)",
                      }}
                      onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        textAlign: "center",
                        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.9)",
                        marginLeft: 15,
                        paddingTop: 5,
                      }}
                    >
                      Start Date
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <DateTimePicker
                    testID="dateTimePicker"
                    value={this.state.rentStartDate}
                    mode={"date"} //The enum of date, datetime and time
                    placeholder="select date"
                    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                    confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                    timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
                    modalTransparent={false}
                    animationType={"fade"}
                    display="default"
                    onChange={this.onChangeStart}
                    style={{ width: 320, backgroundColor: "white" }}
                  />
                </Overlay>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 0.4 }}>
              <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>End Date</Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  alignItems: "center",
                  marginBottom: 5,
                  height: 40,
                  borderRadius: 2,
                  color: "black",
                  borderColor: "rgba(38, 38, 38,0.8)",
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  backgroundColor: "white",
                  paddingEnd: 5,
                }}
              >
                <Text
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 14,
                    paddingLeft: 5,
                    backgroundColor: "white",
                    color: "black",
                  }}
                >
                  {this.state.endDate}
                </Text>
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.toggleOverlay2()}>
                  <Image
                    source={require("../images/calendar_ic_gray.png")}
                    style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }}
                  />
                </TouchableHighlight>

                <Overlay
                  isVisible={this.state.visible2}
                  onBackdropPress={() => {
                    this.combine_toggleOverlay2();
                  }}
                >
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 5 }}>
                    <Icon
                      name="ios-calendar"
                      size={26}
                      resizeMode={"contain"}
                      style={{
                        elevation: 5,
                        justifyContent: "flex-start",
                        alignSelf: "flex-start",
                        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)",
                      }}
                      onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
                      }}
                    />
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        alignItems: "center",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        textAlign: "center",
                        color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.9)",
                        marginLeft: 15,
                        paddingTop: 5,
                      }}
                    >
                      End Date
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <DateTimePicker
                    testID="dateTimePicker"
                    value={this.state.rentEndDate}
                    mode={"date"} //The enum of date, datetime and time
                    placeholder="select date"
                    format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                    confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                    cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                    timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
                    modalTransparent={false}
                    animationType={"fade"}
                    display="default"
                    onChange={this.onChangeEnd}
                    style={{ width: 320, backgroundColor: "white" }}
                  />
                </Overlay>
              </View>
            </View>
            
          </View>)
}
}
```